# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at react-router.js?v=265d8ba8:1:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

**Ошибка взялась из неоткуда и не знаю как решить**

main.tsx

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { theme } from './assets/theme/theme';
import App from './app/app';




const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

app.tsx

```
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router';
import { routes } from '../assets/routes/Routes';

export function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={routes}/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

routes.tsx

```
import { Link, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { SignUp } from "../../app/pages/Auth/SignUp/SignUp";

export const routes = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Link to='SignUp'>dfdertertertertertfdf</Link>
    },
    {
        path: 'SignUp',
        element: <SignUp/>
    }
])
```

SignUp.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, useTheme } from '@mui/material'


export const SignUp:React.FC<any> = () => {

  const theme = useTheme()

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh', background: theme.palette.background.default }}>
      Test
    </Box>
  )
}
```

[image: Скрин ошибки]